# Capture IP and URL of referrer

Tags: 8

This code is adapted from /*core/modules/statistics/statistics.php*. It uses a JavaScript file that sends an uncached POST request to the server (to ensure the code within gets run for every page request).

I want my code within to capture the IP and URL of the referrer. I've tried many things to grab this information and write it to the log, but no luck.

Whatever I do, I get a variation on `Error: Call to a member function *something* on null in...`. Like, I'm not getting anything. For example, the below throws: `Error: Call to a member function getClientIp() on null in main() (line 26 of...`.

Any ideas?

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Store access data.
 */

use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
// use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
// use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation;

chdir('../..');

$autoloader = require_once 'autoload.php';

$kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest(Request::createFromGlobals(), $autoloader, 'prod');
$kernel->boot();

// $container = $kernel->getContainer;

// $request = $kernel->getContainer()->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
// $request = $kernel->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

// $url = \Drupal::request()->server->get('HTTP_REFERER');

// $hostname = $request->getClientIP();
// $hostname = \Drupal::request()->getClientIp();

\Drupal::logger('sitelog')->notice(REQUEST_TIME);
```

---

Working code:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Store access data.
 */

use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

chdir('../..');

$autoloader = require_once 'autoload.php';

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod');
$kernel->boot();

$hostname = $request->getClientIP();
$url = $request->server->get('HTTP_REFERER');

\Drupal::logger('sitelog')->notice($hostname . ' - ' . $url);
```

Comment: Is this a general PHP file? Aren't you planning to do this inside a module or something? I think your Drupal might not be getting bootstrapped correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there, here is a rewritten version of your code that should work:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Store access data.
 */

use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$autoloader = require_once 'autoload.php';

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod');
$kernel->boot();

$client_ip = $request->getClientIP();
$headers = $request->server->getHeaders();
$referer_url = isset($headers['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $headers['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

\Drupal::logger('sitelog')->notice($referer_url . '::' . $client_ip);
```

The main idea of the rewrite is to keep a reference to the HttpFoundation\Request from the very beginning and use if to get access to the parameters you want.

P.S.: Loading Symfony's components as well as booting Drupal's kernel may be an overkill for getting the client's IP and referer url, a simple php script could do that for you and write logs in a file.

Comment: Marking as correct because it got me 90% of the way there. Needed a minor tweak to get the referrer URL. Posted final code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the API to automatically get the IP Address of the referrer. You will need to do a DNS Lookup after getting the authority of the referrer.

See a similar question here and answer. Notice that two below this answer the asker shows his implementation of how to get the IP address using DNS lookup.

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26330010/How-do-I-get-the-referral-IP-address.html#a33211593

Have you successfully completed a request using this script yet?